# how to get header, body (POST type) from webview request, response on android

Tags: android

I using a webview on an android application.
I wanna get header and body (`POST` parameter) information from a response request when the webview loads.

In my iOS application I already get them using this code:

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

        NSString *username = [self queryDictionary:request][@"username"];

        if (username) {
            self.userid = username;
        }
        return YES;
    }


    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

        NSCachedURLResponse *resp = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:webView.request];
        NSString *status = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)resp.response allHeaderFields][@"Authentication"];
        if ([status isEqualToString:@"OK"] && ![self.userid isEqualToString:@""]) {
            // TODO: 서버 API 필요
            AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            NSLog(@"send to server with user id (%@), token %@ ", self.userid, appDelegate.registrationToken);

        } else if ([status isEqualToString:@"failuer"]) {
            self.userid = @"";
        }
    }
```

How can achieve the equivalent result on Android?